# Mime-view: wrap automatically

Tags: email, wanderlust

Wanderlust uses "mime-view" internally for displaying mail messages. Sometimes "text/plain" messages actually have very long lines (like "text/flowed".

If in mime-view I toggle `visual-line-mode` message is displayed correctly. I've tried to add the following hook:

```el
(add-hook 'mime-display-text/plain-hook
  (lambda ()
    (visual-line-mode t)))
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work - `visual-line-mode` is set, but message is still displayed unwrapped. Any ideas how that could be solved?

Comment: Change `mime-display-text/plain-hook` to `mime-view-mode-hook` and you should be in business.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work

Comment: Something else then is likely affecting your configuration -- consider recursively bisecting your configuration to find out why the `mime-view-mode-hook` is insufficient to enable `visual-line-mode` locally in a message buffer that is being viewed with Wanderlust.  It *should* be sufficient.  And, if you haven't restarted Emacs, you of course want to do that.

Comment: The thing which confuses me is that `visual-line-mode` **is** actually enabled, but it has no effect until disabling/enabling again.

Comment: If you open up `simple.el` and search for `define-minor-mode visual-line-mode` you will see all of the variables that are used to give the user a `visual-line-mode` experience.  You *likely* have something in your configuration that conflicts by setting one or more of those variables that are used by `visual-line-mode`.  To fix your problem, you will need to remove the conflicting items from your personal user configuration.  That is the most likely scenario.  Of course, check your `*Messages*` buffer to see if there are any errors when loading Emacs and/or when using Wanderlust.

Answer (score 2):

Format `text/plain` should not have long lines — wrapping is only allowed for `text/plain; format=flowed`.  Unfortunately, while Apple did get it correct in previous versions, recent versions of Apple's `Mail.app` tend to send `text/plain` with long lines.

I work around this with the following code:

```
(defun wl-summary-refill-message ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (wl-summary-set-message-buffer-or-redisplay)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (re-search-forward "^$")
    (while (looking-at "^$")
      (forward-line 1))
    (let ((buffer-read-only nil))
      (fill-region (point) (point-max)))))

(define-key wl-summary-mode-map "\M-q" 'wl-summary-refill-message)
```

When I encounter an incorrect message, I type `M-q` in the summary buffer, which wraps the text.  The wrapped message will get cached, so the wrapping will persist if you come back to the message.  You can undo the wrapping with `C-u .`.

Comment: I've ended up with a similar solution through additional key binding, although I use the same method as above, i.e. forcing `visual-line-mode`.

Comment: and unfortunately it's not related only to Apple Mail messages